# Making part of a div transparent

Tags: html, css

[image: Example Image]

I'm trying to do something like this in HTML. It's a header, at the very top of the page. The checkerboard area must be transparent.

I can't think of a good way to do this without using like 15 divs.

Comment: +1 for a good question.  Is it imperative that it be done without any background images?

Comment: You may use SVG to implement such a design.

Comment: As said above, your best bet may be to use transparent images such as gif, SVG, or png images. Simply just layer the div's and place the images as background images in your CSS. It's clean, neat and very easy to acomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: @Michael: Not at all, whatever will make this work cleanly and compatibly.

Comment: Do you want it to be transparent because you want to show something which is behind the header or simply you just want to have the same background of the body in that specific area?

Comment: @AliBassam: It needs to have the same background as the body in that area, but the background of the body in that area is a pattern. If I can't get any of the other ideas here to work, I'll center-top align the background pattern and just make it look transparent.

Comment: @Tycho Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/CYLFv/ , Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Tycho Using `kleinfreund`'s code I managed to get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yentup/fyXby/2/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Future Options

The ideal scenario would be to use a single element with no images.

Masking and/or clipping would be helpful in situations like this, though browser support is limited. It does seem that progress has been made on the spec (below) since I first wrote this answer, so that's encouraging.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

## Practical Approach

For now, I would go with an image-based solution. It doesn't need to be complex.

I recommend avoiding raster graphics since high-density displays are becoming more and more common (nearly every tablet/smartphone and 4K PC monitors). To accomplish this, SVG will work in most modern browsers and PNG can be used as a fallback.

## Demos

- Here's a demo using a PNG: http://jsfiddle.net/MxspA/6/.
- Same demo with IE7 support: http://jsfiddle.net/MxspA/9/ (replaces `:before` and `:after` with extra elements).

**Source for IE8+ Version**

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="knockout"></div>
</div>

#box{ 
    position: relative; 
}

#knockout {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXHM0.png);
    width: 105px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}

#knockout:before{
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: -52px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
}

#knockout:after{
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    right: -52px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

**Images**

Here's a transparent PNG to get you started. Someone with basic Adobe Illustrator skills could recreate this as an SVG image, providing the aforementioned high resolution capabilities. An SVG will work nicely as a background image.

[image]

Comment: I like this solution. This website must have IE7+ support and the browser test tools I'm using tell me it's working perfectly.

Thanks!

Comment: Glad it works. IE7 will need a tweak, though, since it doesn't support `:before` and `:after`. I created an example which works in IE7 too: http://jsfiddle.net/MxspA/9/

Answer (score 8):

It may be possible with a CSS-alpha mask: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks

**update 1**

- Create a `DIV`-layer ontop
- Insert a `CANVAS`-element. Paint the black parts black, the rest should be transparent.

**update 2**

I am pretty sure, that there is no way to create this layout without using PNG-images with an alpha-layer in older browser.

Comment: Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS%20mask

More examples: https://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/

Comment: The link in the answer is broken

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: extended my demo with the help of @yentups posted fiddle again.

I played around a bit with radiant gradients and came up with the following. You have to play around a bit and get used to the syntax of radial gradients. It's late for me now, I won't wrap my head around this now. Good luck!

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5VDLX/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="shape"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    background: yellow;
}
.shape {
    width: 500px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 100%, circle, transparent 50px, black 0);
    background-image: radial-gradient(50% 100%, circle, transparent 50px, black 0);
}
.circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid red; /* red for demonstration */
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: -51px 0 0 199px; /* considering borders */
}
```

- Browser support for CSS3 gradients
  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients
- Browser support for CSS3 background-image options http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

Comment: +1 - very nice. I added a JS Fiddle demo. It's worth noting that browser support isn't complete for `radial-gradient` and the edges of the gradient look rough (at least in Chrome) as though there is no alpha blending on the edges.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Sure I've also tested with jsfiddle. Just forgot the link. ;) And indeed: This will need some tweaking! PS: I've added a new demo.

Comment: Looks much nicer...the second circle hides the rough edges of the knockout.

Comment: VERY nice. Been researching masking for about three hours now and this was the nicest I've found so far.

Comment: I found a bug when using border-radius for the .shape: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=235775

Answer (score 5):

Using `kleinfreund`'s code:
This [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yentup/fyXby/)

Fully working page example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yentup/fyXby/3/show)

Comment: Thank you. This looks way better than my approach – I was quite lazy – I used your approach and refined it a bit.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I kept trying to figure this out and it wouldn't work without your code

Answer (score -1):

```
**Demo Working Link** - https://codepen.io/iamabhishek/pen/ddoomE

**HTML**
<div class="main">
  <div></div>
</div>

**css**
div.main{
    width:50%;
    height:550px;
    background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503135935062-b7d1f5a0690f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=cf4d0c234ecaecd14f51a2343cc89b6c&dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=376&h=564&q=60&cs=tinysrgb') no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover
}
div.main>div{
    width:100px;
    height:320px;
    background:transparent;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    border-top:25px solid orange;
    border-left:120px solid orange;
    border-bottom:25px solid orange;
    border-right:10px solid orange;
    margin-left:150px

}
```