# Is it possible to cut out a triangle section from a div using CSS?

Tags: css

Is it possible to cut a triangle from a `<div>` like in the picture below?

The background is actually not just colour, but in my case is a blurred picture, so I can’t simply cover the green `<div>` with a brown triangle image. Is there some other CSS way to achieve this effect? Thanks.

[image: example of div cut]

Comment: Is `z-index` an option in your particular case?

Comment: Create a triangle (http://www.css3shapes.com/), position it absolute, z-index higher that background, win.

Comment: @Joren: nope. He’s trying to create a triangular section of the `<div>` where the background behind the `<div>` shows through, if you see what I mean.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite if so, then `shape` it and set background for it, like it's in the `div`

Comment: @EL: when you say “`shape`it”, what do you mean?

Comment: @Paul D. Waite I mean as Joren said

Comment: @PaulD.Waite whoops, typical case of reading too quickly. My bad.

Comment: @EL: okay. So you’re saying create a triangle, then set the background of that to the same blurred picture background that the body has?

Comment: @Paul D. Waite I think it's obvious =)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The illusion of it is possible: http://jsfiddle.net/2hCrw/4/

Tested with: IE 9, 10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari on PC and iPad.

- `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements are skewed to provide a side of the triangle each.
- Wrapper used for clipping skewed pseudo elements. You may be able to avoid this by using your outer container as the wrapper.
- Elements can still be styled with borders, shadows, etc.
- Anything underneath will show through properly.

Demo with borders and drop shadow: http://jsfiddle.net/2hCrw/8/

<sub>This demo also adds a tweak for iPad with Retina to prevent a gap between the element and the pseudo elements (either caused by drop shadow bleed or sub-pixel rendering behavior).</sub>

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="test">test</div>
</div>


#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 116px;
}
#test {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
#test::before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: -8px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 16px;
    top: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-40deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-40deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-40deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-40deg);
    transform: skew(-40deg);
}
#test::after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    right: -8px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 16px;
    top: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transform: skew(40deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(40deg);
    -o-transform: skew(40deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(40deg);
    transform: skew(40deg);
}
```

---

As an alternative, you can use a transparent image and "extend" the element above it with pseudo elements. I have [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717432/making-part-of-a-div-transparent/14717531#14717531) regarding a circle cut from an element and show support options down to IE7 (as well as future options for true clipping/masking in CSS).

Comment: Awesome solution! Way to think outside the box on this one. If only it were possible to skew just one side of a div.

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this with [CSS masks](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/masking/index.html) ([examples](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/)):

- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgbEH (anti-triangle mask)
- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEufn (triangle mask)

I used `clip-path: polygon(…)` property but only my Chrome seems to support it; you could instead create polygon images and reference them with `mask-image` for broader support.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to cut from divs in css, but it is possible to use an image overlaying the div to make it look like it has been cut.

```
.triangle{
    background-image: url('cut.png');
    width: 24px; height: 24px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute; top: 32px; left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: obviously it is possible

Comment: I interpreted the question differently. sorry guys.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there’s a bit of a drop shadow on your `<div>` as well, which I’m guessing the triangle should respect.

CSS doesn’t currently provide a way to achieve this directly. One approach would be to create an image of the green bottom area of the `<div>` with the triangle cut-out in it (using e.g. Photoshop), set it as the background of a `<div>` inside your original `<div>`, and position it outside of your original `<div>`.

Here’s a JS Fiddle example that hopefully explains the idea:

- http://jsfiddle.net/7y6nz/