# Hide quarter of a div

Tags: html, css, position

How can I achieve the following, both are divs,
The visisble div has a color.
The hidden div is transparant and the top right part of the visible div has to be transparant too.

```
            ------------
            |//////////|
--------------------///|
|           |/hidd/|///|
|           |///en/|///|
|           |//////|///|
|           -------|----
|                  |
|      visible     |
|                  |
|                  |
--------------------
```

edit: or is there a way that I can mask the top right corner of the visible div, it has to be transparant.

Comment: I guess this won't be possible as you wish. If the visible div is just filled with color you could use a work around, like using multipple divs. But as far as I know you can't achieve transparency with overlaying divs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717432/making-part-of-a-div-transparent

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ubfvj

Comment: Maybe this can help you? http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-masking/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for overlapping divs.

Additional idea is to separate back rectangle/square into 4 parts and make 1 part's background color transparent.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="back"></div>
<div class="front"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.back {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 300px;
}

.front {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  top:100px;
  left:100px
}
```

Additionally,

Here is the idea with playing with opacity and hiding 3/4 parts of the image - 
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwExh)

Good luck

Comment: I have to hide 1/4 of the part, not 3/4

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, but you could use 2 div's with the same background color one next to the other but having different sizes and a container div.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/a455b6at/1/

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one">div1</div>
    <div id="two">div2</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        display:block;
    }
    #one {
        background-color: red;
        width: 100px;
        height: 200px;
        display: block-inline;
        float:left;
    }
    #two {
        background-color: red;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: block-inline;
        margin-top: 100px;
        float:right;
    }
```

Comment: It has to be one div, not 2