# Child Element That Allows Sight Through Parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to have the background of a child element show the elements behind it's parent? For example, if you wanted to focus on a section of the page you could put up an opaque overlay, then position a child element that was clear where you wanted to see the original page. In my particular case I cannot use an image because the clear element needs to follow the user's cursor to reveal different parts of the page.

Comment: I think this can be done using the css opacity property on the element.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: Unfortunately that's like putting a piece of glass against a wall in an attempt to see through the wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something similar here [Making Part of a Div Transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717432/making-part-of-a-div-transparent)

Comment: The end goal was to have the clear element follow the user's mouse, making the use of an image practically impossible, but this is the correct answer. I'll mark it if there isn't a better answer soon. Thank you.

Comment: No problem at all.  It is an interesting question.  I think there is also something called css masking.  Not sure if it is actually on all browsers,but you could take a look. https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Answer (score 2):

Using javascript I was able to resize four elements to cover the area around the one child div.

```
<div id="top" style="width:100%; top:0px;">Move your mouse!</div>
<div id="right" style="right:0px;"></div>
<div id="left" style="left:0px;"></div>
<div id="bottom" style="width:100%; bottom:0px;"></div>
<div id="center"></div>
```

[Working jsFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/t2hy0v8w/6/)